# VB.NET hwnd destroy/disable/hide menu

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I've found a lot of information about adding MenuItems with hwind, but I want to remove/disable/hide the menubar on an external Program.

I know how to Remove the Border and Window Title with hwind, but I've no idea how to remove the menu bar.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

---

EDIT: 
I can't post any pictures here from SPY++ because I'm new. 
Here is the TreeView from the Program handle:

WINDOW XXXXXX Afx:400000:b:10005:6:213078f

- WINDOW XXXX AfxFrameOrView42u
- WINDOW XXXX msctls_statusbar32
- **WINDOW XXXX AfxControlBar42u**

  -- WINDOWS XXXXX ToolbarWindow32
- WINDOW XXXX AfxControlBar42u
- WINDOW XXXX AfxControlBar42u
- WINDOW XXXX AfxControlBar42u

If I open the propertys of the highlited handle it shows me following style options:

WS_CHILDWINDOW
WS_VISIBLE
WS_CLIPSIBLINGS
WS_CLIPCHILDREN
CBRS_BORDER_BOTTOM
CBRS_ALIGN_TOP

So can I now change the style property and remove WS_VISIBLE?

Thank you so much!

Comment: It depends on how the menu is implemented. We don't know that. We don't even know what this program is. Please do realise that programs are free to, and do, implement their UI in many different ways.

Comment: Could you post the application/program name you want to remove this menu bar from. It's easy to get a handle of this using Spy++, but without knowing the name it's hard to know where to get it.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for the fast reply. I can't tell you the name of the application. The application use a MenuStrip I'm able to add an menu item to the menu bar with SetMenuItem. It would be so great if I could hide the MenuStrip bar. I will post the code on which I've worked tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've got the solution!

Import:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

Declaration:

```
<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function GetMenu(hWnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SetMenu(hWnd As IntPtr, hMenuOld As Int32) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Sub:

```
Private Sub RemoveMenuBar()
    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses()
          If p.ProcessName = "PROCESS" Then
          Dim hwnd As IntPtr = p.MainWindowHandle
          Dim sysMenu = GetMenu(hwnd)
          SetMenu(hwnd, Nothing)
       End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you for the help!